# How to get the larger image in another page when clicked on small image using SESSION

Tags: php, image, session

I'm working with images for a website. I have an two images one is smaller and other is larger in sizes. When I click on the image of small one, in another page, larger image should be seen. I'm using SESSIONS to send larger image path to the another page.

Below code for small image:

```
echo "<div id='ru'>
 <a href='lrgimgview.php'><img src='".$path."'/></a>
     <p>Muggu ".$imagenumber[$i]."</p>
     </div>";
$_SESSION['lrgimgv']=$imagepathl;
```

$path has the path of smaller image

$imagepathl has the path of larger image,
when I click on link i.e on image, larger image is shown in another page.

In the another page('lrgimgview.php')

```
<img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['lrgimgv']; ?>">
```

The above code works fine for single image.

Now, I have multiple images.

How to get the larger image in another page when clicked on small image?

I tried something like this

```
foreach($imagepath as $i =>$path)
{

$imagepathl[$i]=$lPath;     

echo "<div id='ru'>
<a href='lrgimgview.php'><img src='".$path."'/></a>
<p>Muggu ".$imagenumber[$i]."</a>
</div>";
}
```

Able to see the smaller images in a page, but when clicked on smaller image, not getting the larger image in another page.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are hiding the image path for some kind of security or URL shortening purpose so I won't explain the usage of `$_GET` and query strings which could be used, but not achieving what you're looking for.

Instead, you could try using a multi-dimensional `$_SESSION` variable.

Take the `$imagepathl` that you've created in the `foreach` loop and assign it to `$_SESSION` like so after the loop has completed:

```
$_SESSION['lrgimgv'] = $imagepathl;
```

and modify your URL in the `foreach` loop to include the index in the query string:

```
echo "<div id='ru'>
<a href='lrgimgview.php?id=".$i."'><img src='".$path."'/>
<p>Muggu ".$imagenumber[$i]."</p></a>
</div>";
```

You can later access the image path stored in the `$_SESSION` variable by using

```
$_SESSION['lrgimgv'][$_GET['id']]
```

You could also store all of this inside of a table instead of persisting this data over sessions. I'd highly recommend this over using `$_SESSION` variables because you will probably overwrite data as your users start using multiple pages!

Comment: I have made the changes and it is working fine and better way. Thank you and I accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use session variable here. As you assign new value to session variable, old ones gets overwritten.

Instead, send the $imagepathl in the querystring to lrgimgview.php, and use $_GET to retrieve that variable.

So it should look like this on small image page:

`<a href='lrgimgview.php?imagel=$imagepathl'><img src='".$path."'/></a>`

And this on large image page:

`<img src="<?php echo $_GET['imagel']; ?>">`